# Is it possible to access vim's command-line arguments in vimscript?

Tags: vim

I found the answer to this question while writing it, so I've broadened it a little.  I wanted to access the `--servername` argument, in order to create dynamic settings in my `.vimrc` file.

Through vim's help, I found the `v:servername` variable, and my script is working.  However, now I'm curious if it's possible to access any arbitrary command-line argument.  For example, if I wanted to know if vim was in Lisp mode (`-l`) or Debugging mode (`-D`), how would I do it?  There seems to be no corresponding `v:` variable for them.

Here are the variables I found by autocompleting `:help v:<Tab>`
[image]

Is there a general way to access command-line arguments from vimscript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strangely, I think the answer may be "No, there is no direct way to access startup options specified on the command line".

The `:args` command and `argv()` can be used to access the filename(s) specified on startup, but that's not what you want.

I see on Vim's forums that someone offered this solution to get the startup command line on Linux:

```
:exe '!tr "\0" " " </proc/' . getpid() . '/cmdline'
```

I assume there's analogous command on Windows. . . .

You can look over that forum thread here:

http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use/browse_thread/thread/43773f27cdc10265/ad17ae8180c0fb6e?show_docid=ad17ae8180c0fb6e

Comment: Thanks.  The solution is equivalent to the other answer, marking correct because of the citation.

Answer (score 10):

My googling indicates that this feature has been proposed but never implemented. However I did come up with a bit of a kludge that nevertheless works:

```viml
:echo split( system( "ps -o command= -p " . getpid() ) )
# => [ 'vim', ... arguments ... ]
```

(Tested on OS X Lion.)

The `getpid()` function gets Vim's PID, then we call `ps` externally with options to return nothing but the "command" value for process, then use `split()` to split the command into a list.

Comment: Set a variable such as `s:result` with this, then combine with `count(s:result, '-q')` to find out if a particular option (such as `-q`, for example) is used. This will let you know whether a command line option was used. In my example using `-q`, you can tell if you are in `quickfix` mode. Alas, checking `&buftype` does not always work, especially during initialization in `.vimrc`.